# Angular binding equivalent of a FallbackValue?

Tags: angularjs

So in XAML there's a handy little binding base attribute you can set called `FallbackValue` that I use often when designing in instances where I may not have data immediately available but also don't need to actually go set up design time data either.

I'm trying to find if there's an equivalent to this in Angular binding I can use for the same purpose. Basically just a quick/simple way to have some display data when the binding fails?

Like in XAML `Text="{Binding Blah, FallbackValue=FAIL}"` would display FAIL if there's no data. Is there a one liner equivalent for Angular as well? So far my searches haven't found a solution but maybe I'm just not using the right nomenclature. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

Script

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.greeting = "hello";
  $scope.anotherGreeting = undefined;  
});
```

HTML

```
 <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
       {{ greeting || 'No greeting' }}
        {{ anotherGreeting || 'another greeting is undefined!' }}
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here's a plunkr for reference: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/xkXlfoG6sBhgyzjHz6iw?p=preview